# Функция imap_searh находит не все письма.

Tags: php, imap

Привет.
Использую метод `imap_search` для парсинга писем с Яндекс-почты. Во время теста скрипта заметил такое: иногда `imap_search` возвращает мне не все письма.
Допустим, у меня их 5, а возвращает 4, причем теряет последнее. Получается это когда несколько раз запускаю код.
Вопрос: кто-то сталкивался с этим? Или это происходит из-за того, что часто запускаешь `imap_search`? Вроде как при первом запуске всегда правильное кол-во писем возвращается.

Comment: @Влад Дяченко, выложите, пожалуйста, ваш скрипт, чтобы сообщество могло точнее определить причину вашей проблемы.

Comment: imap_search($config, 'FROM "'.$email.'" ON "'.$date.'"');